# How to disable a jquery function from executing for a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that calculates the distance between two slideshows and detects to see if they have been scrolled past yet and tells it to display the first slide with important information on it.

However, it displays it once, but then the `if` statement loops and keeps displaying it, which would be expected.

I am wondering if there is a way to force the function to wait 25-ish seconds before it executes again? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the jQuery code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.infoIdentifier').each(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectpos = $(this).offset().top - 600;
    var nextobject = $(this).parent().nextAll('.slideshow').children(".infoIdentifier")
    if (nextobject.length === 0) {
      var nextobjectpos = 10000;
    } else {
      var nextobjectpos = nextobject.offset().top - 600;
    }
    if (scroll > objectpos && scroll < nextobjectpos) {
      var $this = $(this).parent('.slideshow');
      var $currentSlide = $this.find('.active');
      var $nextSlide = $this.children('.jumbotron').first();
      $nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
      $currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

As for HTML, the slideshows are held in a main container, and each slide show with important information is tagged as `class = 'infoIdentifier'`. This part of the function does its job. The calculations are fine and the application of classes is fine, however, how do I disable the `if (scroll > objectpos && scroll < nextobjectpos){` statement for x amount of seconds. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this. I added a boolean outside of your scroll function called `wait`, which is set to `false` initially.

Then I added `!wait` as a condition to your `if` logic, which means it will only validate if `wait` is currently `false`.

Then inside that block, I set `wait` to `true`, and started a `setTimeout` for 25 seconds, after which `wait` is set back to `false`.

During those 25 seconds, that slideshow code will not run.

```js
var wait = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.infoIdentifier').each(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectpos = $(this).offset().top - 600;
    var nextobject = $(this).parent().nextAll('.slideshow').children(".infoIdentifier")
    if (nextobject.length === 0) {
      var nextobjectpos = 10000;
    } else {
      var nextobjectpos = nextobject.offset().top - 600;
    }
    if (!wait && scroll > objectpos && scroll < nextobjectpos) {
      var $this = $(this).parent('.slideshow');
      var $currentSlide = $this.find('.active');
      var $nextSlide = $this.children('.jumbotron').first();
      $nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
      $currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');

      wait = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        wait = false;
      }, 25000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another question, would it be possible to put the `window.scroll` function in the `each` function so that each separate slide has its own timer, I tried switching their positions and assigning each `each` function its own wait var and it didn't work, any thoughts?

Comment: I seemed to have answered my own question, I swapped the each and scroll function and set `$(this) = $this` and it seems to be working. Thank you for your help.